# How can I apply two xml drawable files to an android:background property

Tags: android

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner2"
        android:onClick="signin"
        android:text="SIGN IN"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />
```

xml files: custom_bg.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorHighlight"></solid>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

rounded_corner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!-- view background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="#c62828">
    </solid>

    <!-- view border color and width -->
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ccc">
    </stroke>

    <!-- If you want to add some padding -->
    <padding
        android:left="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp">
    </padding>

    <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp">
    </corners>

</shape>
```

How can I use these two xml files in my Button View as an `android:background` property?

Comment: thanks @tachyonflux. I had an error in the xml file where i applied d combined.xml. there was the error sign by the side of the android:background property.

Answer (score 2):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/grren_button" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tv_background"/>
```

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/signup_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/password_signup"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layer1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Sign up"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    >
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `layer-list`:

combined.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_bg" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner"/>
</layer-list>
```

**Note**: you can also combine everything into one file by moving everything between the `<item>` tags instead of using the `android:drawable` property.